# ubuntu slow on ssh/sftp connecton

Tags: ssh, authentication, sftp

I recently purchased vps server with ubuntu.

when i test it worked file.

but now i found a problem..

after i worked about 1hours it gets slows down while connecting/authentication to server.

first i followed following link/post:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65068/why-ssh-takes-a-long-time-to-connect
http://ask.xmodulo.com/fix-slow-ssh-login-issue-linux.html

and un-comment "GSSAPIAuthentication no" line and also added "UseDNS no" line.

then restart server and it seems to be solved the issue.

but again after about 1hour of works it get slowed down on connecting/authentication to server.

it's takes almost 30 second to pass that state on putty, winscp even on filezilla.

so, i get confused what is the issue for that?

any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: It would help.if you could add some verbose output from the connection (when it's sllow)

Comment: @SebastianStark, sir, how i can display/export verbose output as i am using putty? and also a hint, sir, if i restart the server "reboot" command it seems to work find as it should.  Then again after 1 hour get slowed down.

Comment: no idea how to do that with putty. What are you doing on the server during this hour?

Comment: @SebastianStark, sir, my purpose on this server is to bridge data transfer. So, nothing heavy runs on this server. only core linux (ubuntu). so, i just user 2 thing, use wget using puty/ssh to get file from siteA. then use winscp to download that file form vps to my local  system. I made a software to run that in batch. I hope that makes sense?